# What kind of IC is "ATMLU324" "16B 1" "Z8J0534B"?

Tags: datasheet, attiny

I recently bought what I thought it would be an ATtiny85. After a few unsuccessful tests, I discovered (guess what?) true ATtiny85 had "ATtiny85" printed on it, like this one:

[image]

Mine is this one:

[image]

The printing says:

```
ATMLU324
16B 1
Z8J0534B
```

I searched for a datasheet, but all I found was datasheet sites searching for it too. What is this chip?

Comment: Where did you buy it?

Comment: Yes @MarcusMüller

Comment: what @marcelm said. Where did you buy it, and as what was it sold?

Comment: Maybe you could try asking the seller what in the world he's sold you?

Comment: Contact atmel company.

Comment: @marcelm I bought it in a Brazilian website called MercadoLivre and it was sold as an attiny85. I didn't pay attention to what I was really buying and now I really wanted to know what I bought.

Comment: @Dampmaskin The seller is no longer available on the platform.

Comment: Return it, get your money back, let the ATMLU324 16B 1 Z8J0534B be bought by someone who actually wants an ATMLU324 16B 1 Z8J0534B. Edit: Oh, you got scammed then. Sorry to hear it.

Comment: @GabrielRado So, with > 95% probability this is a counterfeit or garbage, or something that left the factory in ways it shouldn't have, for all we can tell, OR this is really a custom Atmel product that they made for a bigger customer and they had overstock and sold that. And you bought something that **might** work like an Attiny85 in *some ways*, but not in some others. These ICs costs cents new from large distributors. I recommend throwing yours away. You've been scammed. Don't buy electronic components from questionable sellers.

Comment: Oh by the way, the crime here is called fraud (against you), and counterfeiting (against Atmel). Atmel might be nice to you if you tell them.

Comment: @GabrielRado Please include answers to extra questions in your question as well, so anyone trying to help you doesn't have to wade through the comments :)

Comment: @marcelm Learned a lot from you in this questions. Thanks for all advices and question tips. Certainly I will include more info in future questions

Comment: It could be plain IGNORANCE on the part of a seller which sells all kinds of goods - he might assume everything 8-pinned with Atmel on it is an ATTINY...   And wrong/misleading/misled/ignorant descriptions/translations are also rampant on such marketplace websites (compare knives... "willow blade fog"?! ... ahhh, it's a kasumi yanagiba of course :) )

Comment: @rackandboneman ah well, I'll go with "if I'm not a medical professional, I'm probably a criminal if I sell organs" interpretation of what the seller does. Sure, you don't have to be an expert in everything you trade, but assuming equivalence for different parts is definitely not something sellers would do.

Comment: "Wanted organ for our church, got a package of strange meat. Would not buy again."

Comment: Mercado Libre is a spanish or Brazilian copy of eBay slash Alibaba. Buyer  beware. That said, plenty of knock offs work just fine for most people.

Comment: I'm surprised you can't find these locally though. I went to downtown Bogotá and saw so many arduino and parts in so many electronic shops. Not like the desert of electronics that is known as the US. I'm sure most major cities in Brazil are the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks for all the world like an [Atmel AT24C16B](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc5175.pdf), a 16kbit two-wire serial EEPROM chip.

In particular, page 14 of [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc5175.pdf) has this diagram explaining the markings on the DIP version of the chip:

```
                      Seal Year
                       |  Seal Week
                       |   |   |
 |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   A   T   M   L   U   Y   W   W
 |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   1   6   B       1
 |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   * Lot Number
 |---|---|---|---|---|---|---|---|
   |
  Pin 1 Indicator (Dot)

Y = SEAL YEAR             WW = SEAL WEEK
 6: 2006  0: 2010          02 = Week 2
 7: 2007  1: 2011          04 = Week 4
 8: 2008  2: 2012          :: : :::: :
 9: 2009  3: 2013          :: : :::: ::
                           50 = Week 50
                           52 = Week 52
```

Maybe you were simply sent the wrong part by mistake. Or maybe the seller tried to scam you with a cheaper (or counterfeit) part.

Comment: ... and then the seller mysteriously disappeared from the market place they sold the wrong chip on? While I value your belief in the good in mankind...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Or they went out of business because they kept sending customers incorrect parts. You can't just conclude malice from the information we have now.

Comment: Yes, I think I was looking at your first version. I'll remove my comment

Comment: @marcelm fair point, but I'm trying to think of likelihoods here, and that tells me that parts labeled as something else sold from a Argentinian marketplace website with a Brazilian domain selling chips with exactly that marking are available from aliexpress with a seller that disappears isn't a good basis for assuming they did a mistake

Comment: @MarcusMüller Fair enough. And I agree it's certainly _possible_ that it was a scam. No way to be sure though :)

Comment: @marcelm high five :) full agreement

Comment: @MarcusMüller: "There's no need to look for malice in what can easily be explained by human stupidity."

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I believe it should read ATMLU924.

There are multiple sites online that suggest these are knock-off serial eeproms, see

- http://panda-bg.com/en/products/Integrated-Circuits/Memories/Memories-EEPROM/011602/
- http://www.eca.ir/forums/thread33452.html

You could try hooking these up and see if you can still use them as memory. However, if they were advertised as ATtiny85, it's likely that somebody scammed you, unfortunately.

Comment: I went by the picture OP posted. Compare the 9 with the 3 further down.

Comment: Fair enough, they do look slightly different. You may be right.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple pictures with that same code show up on websites like Alibaba, claimed to be an attiny. It's a counterfeit of some kind, maybe it is an attiny inside and will work like one, maybe not. Only way to find out is to try to program it.

Comment: and not even that would prove it works like an Attiny – it might misbehave in strange ways.

Comment: @marcusmüller definitely, it could even be an attiny that failed QA and got stolen instead of destroyed/recycled. Whatever it is, it's probably not worth using